How to install ROS2 under NAOqi OS?
I want to install ROS2(https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/) under my NAOqi OS (read only file system) but figured out that limited support is offered and is installable only on few platforms (Ubuntu, Windows MacOS).
So I resorted to using this simplifying tool (https://ros2-nao.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#building) and the lastest command to perform (colcon build) simply won't execute because the tool is not correctly built under the NAOqi OS of my robot (running Python 2.7).
How to install colcon building tool under NAOqi OS (http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/dev/tools/opennao.html)? given that I want to build it from source and that NAO v2.8 doesn't offer root priveleges nor executes bash since it is based on Yocto distribution (to note that pip install -U colcon-common-extensions doesn't install anything)

Installing on the robot itself would be tricky (you would need to setup a virtual environment on your computer as similar to NAO as possible, build there, and copy the files to NAO), but an alternative is connecting from your computer to NAO using this:
https://github.com/ros-naoqi/naoqi_driver2

for the V2.8 software of NAO 6, how would you setup the virtual environment to build ROS2 ?

Not sure, but an important part is making sure it's a 32-bit system; runing that in VirtualBox could help.
